# How can I achieve an "blinded by light" effect?

Tags: light

First of all, the term I use is definetely not a good one, so as soon as someone know how to describe it please tell me so I can correct it (or correct it directly)

I have a box in the middle of my scene who emit light more and more I as move forward in time. What I'd like to achieve is that at some point, the light begin to be so intense it surexpose the scene and at the ind all the scene is white (well…what the camera get).

I tried pushing the emit value and also change exposure value in the world parameters but its not related.

I assume I'll need to play with the node editor with compositing but is there others ways to do that?

Comment: you could keyframe the scene's [exposure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Odj.png)

Comment: Are you sure changing the emission strength doesn't work? You have to use some pretty extreme values, but eventually everything becomes white.

Comment: eephyne, what happens with 1 billion in emission value? Can you share your blend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will most likely be hard to achieve through the 3D scene alone, and will probably require some post processing and compositing work.

It could probably be achieved with a mix of lens flares and god rays and volumetric lighting.

Volumetric lighting can be made with a volume material in cycles, see this: [Project light through shape, text or symbol to appear in cloud or mist](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52884/project-light-through-shape-text-or-symbol-to-appear-in-cloud-or-mist/52886#52886)

It can also be faked or enhanced in the compositor with the *Filter > Sun Beams* node.

In compositing you can also add a lens flare effect with *Filter > Sun Beams* or *Filter > Glare*

- [Blender God Rays Tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20god%20rays&tbm=vid)
- [Blender Lens Flare Tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20lense%20flare&tbm=vid)

Comment: I just used a mix between sun beams and glare to give me a "random" plus that just sun beams was'nt giving me and thats exactly what I wanted. In the same time I learn how to basically use layers :) thanks