# How to get the bloom / blown out glow effect?

Tags: rendering, effects

I want to render a scene and have it look like one of those old videos or images where the lights have trails (even in a still) and there is a blown out look.

Is this something I would do in the compositing step or through my settings in the render?

Does anyone have an idea how to make a render look like this?

[image]

Comment: you need to do it with the Compositing, and use effects like (I guess) Blur and Glare

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53748/how-can-i-achieve-an-blinded-by-light-effect/53750