# Is there any tutorial to render shining lights effect like the one shared in the link below

Tags: rendering, lighting

i want to create a stadium scene and have a cinematic shot where stadium lights are shining and emitting out light as shown in the 2D picture below. Is there any tutorial that i can follow to create something like this. I just want to know how can i render this effect for one light.

[image]

Comment: If you use Eevee, there's a Bloom effect in the Render panel. In Cycles you need to do it in the Compositor (use the Glare effect probably)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89653/how-to-make-small-objects-emit-a-ton-of-light/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53748/how-can-i-achieve-an-blinded-by-light-effect https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243040/how-to-get-led-light-appearance-right https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/how-can-i-add-lens-flares-halos/

Answer (score 1):

In Eevee you can activate the *Bloom* effect in the *Render* panel:

[image]

In Cycles (works also in Eevee) you need to go through the *Compositor* and use the *Glare* effect, as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW3qgAaiPik) by Five Minutes Blender:

[image]