# How to make light pass through hole?

Tags: light, lighting

How do I make light go through a half-moon shape hole so it can create a half moon? I wasn't seeing any light come out even though I played around with the strength and put a plane in front of it. No light seemed to emit out of the spotlight. I want it to be like a projector,I've seen other people forum of having the light flickering on and off so I get that.

Update !: I've made the volumetric lighting and plane as suggested, however, I still cannot make the light pass through the plane/half-moon shape without it completely ignoring the plane or shape. It just continues to make a round shape.  [image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: There's nothing for the spot to illuminate.  You need to add a cloud or something at the end of the travel (like Batman) or some volume scattering/absorption extending from the front of the outhouse.

Comment: Like bertmoog mentioned light isn't visible by itself it needs to reflect of something to be visible. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52884/project-light-through-shape-text-or-symbol-to-appear-in-cloud-or-mist and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/correct-way-to-render-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles

Comment: Okay, yeah thank you. I also figured that the light was being displayed on the plane, just couldn't see it due to the light being very low. I had to turn it up to about 500K-700K. Didn't know it could go that far

Comment: Volumetric lighting wasn't working for me as there are probably 3 different light sources (If you count the sky light source). The projector seemed blue/yellow and too many noise

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I had the plane/object too close to the spot light. That's why it didn't work. It needed to be further away from the spot light. Thank you everyone who helped