# How to blend rays with hologram seamlessly

Tags: compositing-nodes

OK before this question gets marked as a duplicate of [How to create a hologram projection with light rays?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57498/how-to-create-a-hologram-projection-with-light-rays) I would like to say that my question is different in that I am trying to get the rays to look like they are streaming down from the hologram and are connected to the variations of colour in the hologram image itself.

To illustrate, this is what I currently have:

[image]

Ideally, it would something similar to this (done in this example with hair particles) but obviously not as jagged and not emanating from the inner parts of the image, but rather the outer parts.[image]

Is there a way to do this?  I tried using weight paint for the image texture to make the hair particles only come from the bottom but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52884/project-light-through-shape-text-or-symbol-to-appear-in-cloud-or-mist

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks but the issue here is that the actual variations in colour have to be projected, not merely a shape.

Comment: Yeah but why not combine it with a [textured lamp](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/correct-vector-input-to-map-texture-light-in-cycles)?

Comment: I tried that but it just looked like a regular lamp and didn't produce the desired result.